# Dynamic routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails application which, among other things, provides a simple wrapper around API calls to a third-party service. I want to set up a route which starts with `/api`, but anything added on to the end of it is taken as a string variable. For example, if a client requests:

```
/api/apps/guid/details
```

...then I want to invoke the `index` action of the controller `ApiController` and make the string `/apps/guid/details` available to it.

I have read through the documentation on controllers and routes, but everything seems to assume that `/apps/guid/details` will be resources within my app, when actually I don't care about the structure of anything after `/api`.

How can I set up a route which allows me to do this?

Comment: Also, I am not sure 'Dynamic routes in rails' is the best title for this question, so I am open to suggestions of a better title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use globbing in your config/routes.rb:

```
get "/api/*path", to: "api#index"
```

Which would be accessible in the controller via `params[:path]`

Details can be found [in the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments).